# Refresh a combobox in a parent tabcontrol page after making an entry in child tabcontrol page

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, tabcontrol

I am using MySQL Database which is connected to Visual Studio Community 2017 Community Edition software. I am using a `TabControl` form, with tables in each `TabPage`. When I add and save records in the first form (i.e. the "Books" form), I would like the Combobox in the second form (i.e. the "Authors" Form) to update after the new record is added in the first form.

The parent form has two textboxes: `txtBookID` and `txtBookName`. The textbook `txtBookID` is autoincremented. The child form has a `ComboBox` called `CboBookID_fkey`. If I make a new entry in the textbook `txtBookName`, I would like the `CboBookID_fkey`, to automatically update with the new `SelectedItem` in the `ComboBox's` drop-down list.

However, when I make an update in the `TextBox` on the parent `TabPage`, the `CboBookID_fkey` `ComboBox` drop-downlist does not automatically update with the changes. I tried to add a fill dataset in the INSERT event but it did not work. I created a `ComboValues` method and called it from the load event of my form, but there were no exceptions/errors. :My vb.net code is shown below: -

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   MyBase.Load

    Dim MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
    "server=localhost;Port=3306;database=mydatabase;userid=root;password=mypassword;persist security info=True"
    daBooks = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * From Books", MysqlConn)

    Dim dtBooks As DataTable = New DataTable()
    daBooks.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    'daBooks.Fill(dsBooks, "Books")
    daBooks.Fill(dtBooks)
    dsBooks.Tables.Add(dtBooks)
    cbBooks = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daBooks)

    dtBooks.Columns("BookID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtBooks.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    'Bind the DataTable to the UI via a BindingSource.
    BookBindingSource.DataSource = dtBooks
    BookBindingNavigator.BindingSource = Me.BookBindingSource

    txtBookID.DataBindings.Add("Text", BookBindingSource, "BookID")
    txtBookCode.DataBindings.Add("Text", BookBindingSource, "BookCode")
    txtBookName.DataBindings.Add("Text", BookBindingSource, "BookName")

    Dim dtAuthors As New DataTable

    daAuthors = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Authors", MysqlConn)
    daAuthors.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
    ' Dim dsAuthors As New DataSet
    dtAuthors = New DataTable("Authors")
    daAuthors.Fill(dtAuthors)
    dsAuthors.Tables.Add(dtAuthors)
    daBooks = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Books", MysqlConn)
    dtBooks = New DataTable("Books")
    daBooks.Fill(dtBooks)
    dsAuthors.Tables.Add(dtBooks)
    cbAuthors = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daBooks)

    dtAuthors.Columns("AuthorID").AutoIncrement = True
    dtBooks.Columns("BookID").AutoIncrement = True

    dtAuthors.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtBooks.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr As DataRow) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtBooks.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dtBooks.Columns(0).AutoIncrementSeed = dtBooks.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).Max(Function(dr) CInt(dr.Item(0))) + 1
    dtBooks.Columns(0).AutoIncrementStep = 1

    dsAuthors.Relations.Add(New DataRelation("relation", dsAuthors.Tables("Books").Columns("BookID"), dsAuthors.Tables("Authors").Columns("BookID_fkey")))

    BookBindingSource = New BindingSource(dsAuthors, "Books")

    CboBookID_fkey.DisplayMember = "BookName"
    CboBookID_fkey.ValueMember = "BookID"
    CboBookID_fkey.DataSource = BookBindingSource

    AuthorBindingSource = New BindingSource(BookBindingSource, "relation")

    'bind the Books' foreign key to the combobox's "SelectedValue"
    CboBookID_fkey.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("SelectedValue", AuthorBindingSource, "BookID_fkey", True))

    'Bind the DataTable to the UI via a BindingSource.
    AuthorBindingSource.DataSource = dtAuthors
    AuthorBindingNavigator.BindingSource = Me.AuthorBindingSource

    txtAuthorID.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorBindingSource, "AuthorID")
    txtAuthorName.DataBindings.Add("Text", AuthorBindingSource, "AuthorName")

    ComboValues()
End Sub

Private Sub BtnBookSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBookSave.Click
    InsertBooks()
End Sub

Public Sub InsertBooks()

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Books (`BookID`, `BookCode`,`BookName`) values (@Bookid,@Bookcode,@Bookname)"
    con = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=mydatabase;userid=root;password=mypassword;persist security info=True")
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(sql, con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bookid", Me.txtBookID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bookcode", Me.txtBookCode.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Bookname", Me.txtBookName.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub ComboValues()
    Dim mycon As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=mydatabase;userid=root;password=mypassword;persist security info=True")

    mycon.Open()
    dtAuthors.Clear()

    Dim daAuthors As New MySqlDataAdapter("select BookName,BookID from Books", mycon)

    daAuthors.Fill(dtAuthors)
    CboBookID_fkey.DataSource = dtAuthors

    With CboBookID_fkey
        .DisplayMember = "BookName"
        .ValueMember = "BookID"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You really need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok, thank you for the advice. I have updated the code

Comment: You seem confused as to what an event actually is.  There is not `INSERT` event.  In your code, `ComboValues` is a method, not an event.  You are calling that `ComboValues` method from the `Shown` event handler, not the `Load` event.  An event handler is a method that is executed when an event is raised.

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're actually asking.  Are you saying that you are adding a record to the database in a second form and you want that record to appear in a `ComboBox` in the first form?  If so then you have no code that could even hope to do that.  You are calling that `ComboValues` method when the first form is displayed and ONLY then.  If you want it to update the `ComboBox` after the new record is added then surely you need to call it again after the new record is added.  There's no sign you've even tried to do that.

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney, I have updated my description based on your comments. A mixup on my part, where the textboxes are in the parent form (i.e. the first form) and the Combobox is in the child form (i.e. the second form). I am saying that I am adding a record to the database in a first form and I would like that record to appear in a ComboBox's drop-down list in the second form. At present, once I add records in the textboxes of the first form, the new record do not show in the Combobox's drop-down list of the second form. I have to stop and restart compiling process .